# MYSQL error occured during the initialization of the runtime system

Tags: mysql

how can i fix this ?

i installed the jre but cannot update it.

check the image below

[SQL Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wU7R3.png)

Comment: can you be more clear on what the problem is

Comment: when i run MySQL, the error in the image appears and i can't fix it

Comment: The error seem clear, did you install JRE?

Comment: ofcourse i did, but still appears

Comment: Uninstall and install again